# sorting value of a map according to key in java

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
/* Returns a Map that stores a contact name as a key and a list of messages from that contact
as a value. If a message has no associated contact, it should not appear in the Map. Must 
not change messages field. Must call filter with an anonymous inner class in the method body. */
public Map<String, List<Message>> sortMessagesByContact() {
    Map<String, List<Message>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Message> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    Predicate<Message> p = new Predicate<>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Message t) {
            return t.getContact().isPresent();
        }
    }; for (Message mg : messages) {
        if (p.test(mg)) {
            map.put(mg.getContact().get(), messages);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

this is what I got so far. 
but i cant figure out a way to put a list of messages from that contact as a value.
btw, i should use anonymous inner class here

so for ex, when printing the map with four messages,

i should get something like this:

```
James = [bakjd],[adjlfaj],[daklfja], Howard = [dajfkla]
```

Comment: Use TreeMap instead? Its naturally sorted by keys.

Comment: And hint: Dont put five lines of /* */ block comments above a method. Write a clear, crisp javadoc instead. Block comments only show up in the editor, there is no point in using them to document methods!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want to use Collectors.groupingBy. i.e. grouping by a key rather than sorting the keys.

```
Map<String, List<Message>> map = 
    messages.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getContact().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mg -> mg.getContact().get()));
```

Comment: thank you very much! but Collectors is not allowed in this assingment.. is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @dkkka you can write code to do the same thing but using a Predicate but not use the Stream API doesn't make much sense imho. Can you use computeIfAbsent?

Comment: @dkkka Map and List are collections, do you mean you can't use streams?

Answer (score 2):

Use TreeMap Class instead of HashMap.

`Map<String, List<Message>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<Message>>();`

TreeMap is sorted by key. In your case key of map is String so it will be sorted alphabetically.